# SAP BO RESTful API returns binary

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

**Summary:**
I have an issue with consuming SAP BO RESTful API. Instead of an expected HTTP response, I'm getting a binary output.

**Details:**
I have two SAP BO servers. One of them works as expected. The other one does not.
When I run "curl" on the "working server":

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json" http://<working-server-ip>:6405/biprws/logon/long
```

I'm getting the correct response:

> {"password":"","clientType":"","auth":"secEnterprise","userName":""}

When I run the same thing on "not-working server":

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json" http://<NOT-working-server-ip>:6405/biprws/logon/long
```

I'm getting "binary" output (curl output below):

> Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to
> tell
> Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider
> "--output Warning: " to save to a file.

I saved this binary output into a file and the content of the binary file looks like below:

> GIOP

**Question:**
Have anyone seen such behavior? It looks like an SAP BO configuration issue, but I've double checked and RESTful app is activated in SAP CMC, and the URL is properly entered.

Any help would be appreciated!

Best regards,
Radek Szwarc

Comment: I don't know what's causing that, but I'd suggest using Fiddler to see if you can get more info about the response, or at least use -I with curl to get the response headers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After executing curl -I ... I got "curl: (8) Weird server reply". I will check with Fiddler.

Comment: Did you check that the port 6405 is really used for the RESTful API ? It could be updated in the CMC, in the WebApplicationContainerServer properties.